# How to use future perfect tense with present or future tense

Tags: difference, present-tense, sequence-of-tenses, future-perfect

I would like to ask the difference between the usage of future perfect tense with present tense and the future prefect tense with future tense.

> We will have eaten food when they come.
> We will have eaten food when they will come.

Which one is correct? The second sentence describes which situation?

Or both have problems?

Does it make sense to say : “We will have eaten before they will arrive”?

We will have eaten by the time they arrive. In this case, "they arrive" is it an assumption situation as "they arrive" is not yet happened?

Comment: Your second version is syntactically invalid. The first one is "valid", but relatively "unlikely / awkward"  for native speakers. We'd be more likely to say, for example, *We will have eaten **by the time** they **arrive***. There's rarely any reason to specify ***food*** after ***eat***, and ***when*** is more natural for "simultaneous" events, rather than indicating that one thing occurred earlier than another. And ***arrive*** usually works better than ***come*** in such contexts.

Comment: Thank you your explanations. Does it make sense to say : We will have eaten before they will arrive?

We will have eaten by the time they arrive. In this case, "they arrive" is it an assumption situation as "they arrive" is not yet happen?

Comment: _We will have eaten before they arrive._ The speaker presumably knows at what time the visitors are expected and is confident that the meal will be over by then.

Comment: Thank you, I also want to know when I can use will arrive in the future perfect tense. The present tense there is like a factual thing, just like: The sun rises?

Comment: If you're simply saying that *something **will** happen* in the future, you need to explicitly indicate the fact of it being in the future by including the highlighted modal auxiliary verb. But if the reference to that future event is dependent upon some context that''s *already* in the future, such as ***I will phone you** when they arrive* (where the highlighted element establishes a future context for the entire utterance), we don't normally keep repeating the modal form to indicate that "future" scope for the "subordinate" verb (*arrive*, there).